What is the limiting probability that three random prime numbers can be the side lengths of a triangle?
Consider sticks of lengths $f(1),f(2),f(3),\dots,f(n)$ where $f(j)=j^\text{th}$ prime number.
Here is an example with $n=50$.

Let $P(n)=$ probability that three randomly chosen sticks can form a triangle.

What is $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P(n)$ ?

I am looking for a closed form for $L$, or if there is no closed form, then an approximation.
Simulations
Simulations suggest that $L\approx 0.46$.

My attempt
Suppose, for a given $n$, we have alreaday chosen $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, and we are about to choose $f(c)$.
If $f(a),f(b),f(c)$ can be the side lengths of a triangle, then $|f(a)-f(b)|<f(c)<f(a)+f(b)$, that is, $f^{-1}(|f(a)-f(b)|)<c<f^{-1}(f(a)+f(b))$.
So the probability that $f(a),f(b),f(c)$ can be the side lengths of a triangle is
$$\frac{\min\left(f^{-1}(f(a)+f(b)),n\right)-f^{-1}(|f(a)-f(b)|)}{n}$$
Then we take the average as $a$ and $b$ run from $1$ to $n$.
$$P(n)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{a=1}^n\sum_{b=1}^n\frac{\min\left(f^{-1}(f(a)+f(b)),n\right)-f^{-1}(|f(a)-f(b)|)}{n}$$
If we use the prime number theorem to approximate $f(j)\approx j\log j$ and $f^{-1}(j)\approx\frac{j}{\log j}$ (which are asymptotic inverses), then
$$P\left(10^2\right)\approx 0.3595$$
$$P\left(10^3\right)\approx 0.4007$$
$$P\left(10^4\right)\approx 0.4246$$
$$P\left(10^5\right)\approx 0.4396$$
but I do not know how to take the limit as $n\to\infty$.
Context
Earlier I found that if $f(j)=j^{1/k}$ then $L=1-\dfrac{1}{\binom{2k}{k}}$, and I seeking a combinatorial proof for this fact.
Now I am wondering what $L$ is, if $f(j)=j^\text{th}$ prime number.

As a crude thought, replacing $p_n$ with $n\log n$ might lead to a decent approximation.

The answer should be $\frac12$, just like the $k=1$ case in your earlier calculation. More generally, if $f(j)$ is reasonably nice and satisfies $\lim_{j\to\infty} \frac{\log j}{\log f(j)} = k$, then the answer should still be your $1-1/\binom{2k}k$.

Simulation for $n$ up to $5\times10^7$: chart. The value for 50 million is $\approx 0.47275$, and this data agrees with @GregMartin's suggestion of $\frac12$.

(Self-answering, after reading comments from @Greg Martin and @Daniel Mathias.)
The answer is $\frac12$.
We have $f(j)=j^\text{th}$ prime number.
$f(j)$ asmptotically approaches $g(j)=j\log j$.
$g''(j)=\frac1j$, so the curvature approaches $0$ as $j\to\infty$. This mean that the graph of $f(j)$ increasingly resembles a straight line as we zoom out, so the probability that three sticks can form a triangle approaches the probability associated with linearly increasing stick lengths, which (based on my previous question) is $\frac12$.
This answer is supported by the chart from @Daniel Mathias' comment. This chart uses an exponential $n$-axis, which allows us to see the asymptotic behavior more clearly.
